# For statement not working

Tags: java, for-loop

Hey I'm new to programming and am exploring Java with eclipse. I'm trying to make a simple program where I can input how many sides the dice has, and how many I want to use. The for statement is giving me trouble though.

Here is what I have.

```
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Random generator = new Random ();
        int sides;
        int num;
        int rolls;
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (sides != 0);
        {

        System.out.println("How many sides does your dice have?(0 to quit)");
        sides = scan.nextInt();

        System.out.println("How many dice would you like to roll?");
        rolls = scan.nextInt();

        for (int num1 : rolls);
            {

                        num = generator.nextInt(sides);
                System.out.println("You rolled a " + num);
            }
        }   
    }
}
```

The for statement says when I hover over the 'rolls' that it "Can only iterate over an array or an instance of java.lang.Iterable". Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Take off this `;` after the `)` in the `for` loop declaration.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html

Comment: Additionally, you're not reading anything into `sides` before your `while` loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program has a Java syntax error, for which the compiler complains,
and a more subtle logical error which is pretty common even among experienced
programmers across the entire C/C++/C#/Java family.

The syntax error is that the kind of **for** that you used needs the you specify
a collection after the colon; or, more correctly, an object of a type which
implements interface **Iterable**. Interfaces define a *contract* that authorizes
the compiler to perform certain operations on the instances of a class which implement
the interface. So, the compiler will handle iteration over a variable only if the
variable is **Iterable**. Since in your case **rolls** is of type **int** (and hence
is not even a class) and **int** is not **Iterable**, you get the error.

You *iterate* on integers using the *classic* **for**, which is supported pretty much with
no differences in C, C++, C# and Java.

```
for (int num1 = 0; num1 < rolls; num1 = num1 + 1)
    /* A single statement (body) */;
```

This statements means: repeat the *body*, that is the *single* statement mentioned after the **for (...)**, exactly **rolls** times. More correctly, it implements the following algorithm:

```
A. Initialize num1 to 0
B. Is num1 lesser than rolls?
    If yes, execute the body, increment num1 and go back to B
    If not, go to the first instruction after the **for**
```

Now, the second problem; this could happen with both flavors of the **for**, but it is unlikely to go unnoticed with the **Iterable** flavor. You most likely don't want a semicolon right after the **for** statement; here's why. A design decision for C and all languages with C-like syntax, like Java, is that in most places where you want to insert one or more statements, only one statement can actually be inserted. The **for** cycle can handle only a single instruction in its body, and it's going to be the one after the *)*, disregarding indentation and coding style. Consider the following two **for** cycles:

```
// Prints numbers from 0 to 9
int x = 0;
for (x = 0; x < 10; x = x + 1)
    System.out.println(x);

// Prints 10
int y = 0;
for (y = 0; y < 10; y = y + 1);
    System.out.println(y);
```

They look alike, but the effect of the first code fragment is printing the numbers from 0 to 9, while the effect of the second is printing 10. The reason is that the body of the second for is actually an empty statement. You could rewrite the two **for**s like this:

```
int x = 0;
for (x = 0; x < 10; x = x + 1)
    System.out.println(x);

int y = 0;
for (y = 0; y < 10; y = y + 1)
    /* Lalala... does nothing at all... */;
System.out.println(y); // When control flow gets here, y equals 10
```

To put more than a statement inside a **for**, you must use a **block**, which is a statement composed of many statements. What's misleading for the beginner, is that blocks doesn't have to be associated with **for**, and actually can exist on their own. The following code in Java is legal:

```
        {
            num = generator.nextInt(sides);
            System.out.println("You rolled a " + num);
        }
```

When you put a **for** which erroneously include the semicolon at the end:

```
        for (int num1 = 0; num1 < rolls; num1 = num1 + 1);
        {
            num = generator.nextInt(sides);
            System.out.println("You rolled a " + num);
        }
```

you are basically saying:

```
        for (int num1 = 0; num1 < rolls; num1 = num1 + 1)
            /* Lalala... does nothing at all... */;
        {
            num = generator.nextInt(sides);
            System.out.println("You rolled a " + num);
        }
```

Hence your for is executing *nothing* exactly **rolls** times, and then it executes the block statement once. Sometimes such errors are mitigated by the fact that the body of a **for** would reference the iteration variable, **num1**, but it is not your case. Consider:

```
    for (int num1 = 0; num1 < rolls; num1 = num1 + 1);
    {
        Console.out.println("Roll No. " + num1);
        num = generator.nextInt(sides);
        System.out.println("You rolled a " + num);
    }
```

This has the ; issue but the compiler detects that there is something wrong because you are using **num1** inside the block statement, but due to the ; the block statement was not associated with the **for**, and hence **num1** is out of scope. The following, although having the same logical error, would not result in a compiler error:

```
    for (int num1 = 0; num1 < rolls; num1 = num1 + 1);
    {
        num = generator.nextInt(sides);
        System.out.println("You rolled a " + num);
    }
```

**Note**: also your **while** has a similar issue of the extra ; character.

Answer (score 2):

The `for ( <type> <name> : <collection> )` in Java expects a collection to the right of the colon `:`. If you want to go through a range of integers, use a different form of `for`:

```
for (int num1 = 0 ; num1 < rolls ; num1++) {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A `for` loop in Java traditionally takes the form of `for (initialization; termination; increment)`.  The `for-each` shortcut was added (relatively) recently and is used to allow simpler looping over implementations of `Iterable` and arrays.

Try using....

```
for (int num1 = 0; num1 < rolls; num1++) {...}
```

...Instead.

Take a closer look at [The `for` statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html) for more details

Answer (score 0):

You want

```
for (int num1 = 0; num1 < rolls; num1++)
```

(with no semicolon after it).

There are two kinds of for loops, range-based over arrays and iterables, and standard ones, where you give it an initialization, a condition for whether to keep going, and something to do after each loop. The three parts are separated by semicolons, like I did above.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are experiencing is that you are essentially attempting to perform a `foreach` when you mean to use a `for` loop.  When you use the notation that you are using `for(T x : Collection<T>)` Notice that you are declaring a variable `int num1` and then attempting to iterate over another number `rolls`.  This can only be used for iterating over collections and not for creating a standard loop.  Instead you should use a standard `for` loop:

```
for (int x = 0; x < rolls; x++);
{

     num = generator.nextInt(sides);
     System.out.println("You rolled a " + num);
}
```